# Salesforce PHP Toolkit: INVALID_TYPE: Must send a concrete entity type

Tags: php, types, salesforce, toolkit

I'm trying to create a Task against a Lead using the PHP Toolkit and this is the error I get:

> INVALID_TYPE: Must send a concrete entity type.#0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\test\sfact\soapclient\SforceBaseClient.php(490):
>   SoapClient->__call('create', Array) #1
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\test\sfact\soapclient\SforceBaseClient.php(490):
>   SoapClient->create(Object(SoapParam)) #2
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\test\sfact\soapclient\SforceEnterpriseClient.php(73):
>   SforceBaseClient->_create(Object(SoapParam)) #3
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\test\sfact\index.php(28):
>   SforceEnterpriseClient->create(Array, 'Task') #4 {main}

Here's my code:

```
$task = new stdclass();
$task->What = 'Lead';
$task->WhatId = 'xxx';
$task->OwnerId = 'xxx';
$task->Type = "Email";
$task->Subject = "Message from Mr. X via Web Contact Form";
$task->Description = "I wrote to you";
$task->Status = "Completed";
$response = $SforceConnection->create( array( $task ), 'Task' );
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you are using the [last Php Toolkit 20.0](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP).

Secondly, see this complete example:

```
require_once ('userAuth.php');
try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

    $fields = array (
    'Status' => 'Completed',
    'Description' => 'I wrote to you',
    'Subject' => 'Message from Mr. X via Web .....',
    'WhoId' => 'xxxxxx',
  );

  $sObject = new SObject();
  $sObject->fields = $fields;
  $sObject->type = 'Task';

  $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));
  var_dump($createResponse);

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $mySforceConnection->getLastRequest();
  echo $e->faultstring;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not the recommended way of doing an insert anymore.  See https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Upsert_Sample_(Enterprise)